# Paypal orders not going through to Magento

Tags: magento, paypal

We have noticed that some customer orders never made it through to magento, but they did go through Paypal. This used to happen when an order would go through a payment review, the payment would be cleared by Paypal after the review was completed, but Magento would never clear it. Is there a reason why some orders are completed on Paypal?s end, but never make it through to Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your missing the Callback IPN Url within Paypal itself.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/paypal_standard_payments_setup_with_ipn

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-for-your-magento-store